# The Dual Maass form for $SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $\phi(z)$ be a Maass form of type $(v_1,v_2)\in \mathbb{C}^2$ for $SL(3,\mathbb{Z})$. Then the dual Maass form $$ \tilde{\phi}(z):= \phi(w.(z^{-1})^{\intercal}.w)\,,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,w=\begin{pmatrix} 
 &   & 1 \\
 & -1&   \\
1 &
\end{pmatrix}$$ is a Maass form of type $(v_2,v_1)$ .

I am having difficulty showing the part $$\Delta_1\tilde{\phi}=\lambda_1\tilde{\phi}\\\Delta_2\tilde{\phi}=\lambda_2\tilde{\phi} $$ where $\Delta_1, \Delta_2$ are the generators of the centre of the ring of differential operators and $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ respectively corresponding to the eigenfunction $I_{v_2,v_1}(z)$ .
 Note that if 
$$z=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_2 & x_3\\
  & 1 & x_1\\
  &   & 1
\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}
y_1y_2 &  & \\
  & y_1 & \\
  &   & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$ then
$$w.(z^{-1})^{\intercal}.w=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x_1 & x_1x_2-x_3\\
  & 1 & x_2\\
  &   & 1
\end{pmatrix}.\begin{pmatrix}
y_2y_1 &  & \\
  & y_2 & \\
  &   & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$ and hence we have 
$$I_{v_1,v_2}(z)={y_1}^{v_1+2v_2}{y_2}^{2v_1+v_2}=I_{v_2,v_1}(w.(z^{-1})^{\intercal}.w)$$ I am not able to see the 'chain rule' the text is  then suggesting to use for the conclusion.

Comment: Isn't $S[f](z) = T [f(\rho(z))](\rho^{-1}(z))$ a differential operator when $T$ is ? (here $\rho(z) = w z^{-\top} w$) Since $T \mapsto S$ is an isomorphism of the ring of differential operators, if $T$ is in center then so is $S$. So at least you know $\phi(\rho(z))$ is a Maass form when $\phi(z)$ is ?

Comment: Yes got it. The point is S is also in the centre and hence is a polynomial in $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$  The eigenvalues comes out from applying S to the last equation i wrote. Thanks